# Android O : Broadcast Limitations PHONE_STATE alternative solution

Tags: android, performance, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have been using android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE for receiving the call state and show the user a dialog once after the call ends to log the call or not?. As from Android O we have to remove the implicit broadcasts from the manifest I need an alternate solution to this where I can listen to the phone call state when when the application is not active. I don't want to use job scheduler as it will kill the user experience. Can anyone suggest me an alternate solution.

Comment: The only option is to register a broadcast receiver in a foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a broadcast receiver in a foreground service or use the job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If your app holds the permission READ_PHONE_STATE, you can still listen to the broadcast `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` in Android O.

I've tested in the official emulator.

Comment: Okay I will check in an emulator. Can you please try checking it in a Pixel or Nexus actual device and post the results?